# Converting array of char into array of integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, int, type-conversion

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure how to convert an array of `char` to an array of `integer`. The task is to have the user input a string of a number sequence of any length (e.g. `12340398687943`, `283792`, etc...), reverse the order of the numbers and then place each individual digit (in the reversed order) into an vector or array of integer type. (i.e. for `12340398687943`, reversed would be `34978689304321`, first integer of int `number[0] == 3`, `number[1] == 4`, `number[2] == 9`, ...and so on)

Below is my code up until the reversing part and I'm stuck in figuring out how to convert each `char` in the array into a `int` type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string stringNumber;

    cin >> stringNumber;

 // Reverses stringNumber
    stringNumber = string(stringNumber.rbegin(), stringNumber.rend());

// Places characters into a vector
    vector<string> charVector(stringNumber.begin(), stringNumber.end());

// Converts charcters into integers
    int numVector[charVector.size];
   for (int i = 0; i < charVector.size(); i++)
       numVector[i] = atoi(charVector[i]);

   return 0

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: `'5' - '0'` yields `5`.

Comment: You can do arithmetic on character literals. Try `charVector[i] - '0'` in your loop, that should point you in the right direction.